# Cannot connect to aiohttp server serving over HTTPS

Tags: python, ssl, tls1.2, aiohttp

Background: I'm writing a web server using `aiohttp` with a websocket endpoint at `/connect`. The app was originally served via HTTP (and clients would connect to `ws://host/connect`). This worked locally using `localhost`, but when I deployed to Heroku, the app was served via HTTPS and it didn't allow clients to connect to an insecure websocket. Therefore, I tried to change my server so that it would use HTTPS locally. Now the client can't even complete the TLS handshake with the server. Here is my setup:

`server.py`

```
from aiohttp import web
import ssl

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', handle)
app.router.add_get('/connect', wshandler)

ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
ssl_context.load_default_certs()

web.run_app(app, port=8443, ssl_context=ssl_context)
# web.run_app(app, port=8443)  # original
```

When I run the server and try to navigate to `https://localhost:8443/` (using Chrome 80), I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/peterwang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 625, in _on_handshake_complete
    raise handshake_exc
  File "/Users/peterwang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/peterwang/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 763, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:1056)
```

I looked at `ssl_context.get_ciphers()` and found that it does include the ciphersuites that Chrome 80 uses also with TLS1.3. I also used Wireshark to trace the communication between the client and my server. I see the TLS Client Hello, which says that it handles TLS1.0 through TLS1.3 and is compatible with a multitude of ciphers that overlap with `ssl_context.get_ciphers()`. There is no response from the server.

Does anyone have any advice? (I am using `Python 3.7`, `OpenSSL 1.1.1d`, and `aiohttp 3.6.2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SSL server has to to be configured to use a certificate matching the servers domain and the associated private key, typically using [load_cert_chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain). Your server is not configured to use a server certificate and key and thus cannot offer any ciphers which requires this - which means it can not offer any ciphers which are typically expected by the client. This means there are no shared ciphers, hence this error.

Comment: what is the best way to generate a valid certificate?  I get an invalid certificate error for certs that I generated locally using openssl